# What is that sloka which says Tirthas reside in our right ear?

Tags: scripture, shloka, rivers

What is that sloka which says Tirthas reside in our right ear?

It is said that when we excrete then our whole body becomes impure but even then our right ear remains pure.

The reason for this is that all holy pilgrimages and rivers (like Ganga etc) reside there.

That is the reason we touch our right ear 3 times after doing pranayama.

I'm looking for that sloka.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are some Shloka found in Parashar Smriti, 12th Chapter [source1](https://archive.org/stream/ParasharaSmriti/SriParasharaSmrithiPdf#page/n113/mode/2up) [source2](http://krishnamuttkondapur.weebly.com/krishna-mutt-blog/achamana1) [source3](https://archive.org/stream/ParasharaSmriti/SriParasharaSmrithiPdf_djvu.txt) [source4](http://literature.awgp.org/akhandjyoti/edition/1947/Dec/17).

> प्रभासादीनि तीर्थानि गंगाद्या सरितस्तथा।
>
> विप्रस्य दक्षिणे कर्णे वसन्ति मनुरब्रवीत॥
>
> According to Manu Prabhas and other teerthas, Ganga and other rivers reside in Brahmana's right ear.
>
> अग्निरापश्च वेदाश्च सोमः सूर्योऽनिलस्तथा।
>
> सर्वे देवास्तु विप्रस्य कर्णे तिष्ठन्ति दक्षिणें॥
>
> Fire, water, the gods, the moon, the sun, and the
> wind, all dwell in the right ear of a Brahman.

There also another Shloka that ia said to be from Parashar Smriti [source1](http://krishnamuttkondapur.weebly.com/krishna-mutt-blog/achamana1) [source2](http://literature.awgp.org/akhandjyoti/edition/1947/Dec/17).

> आदित्यावसवो रुद्रा वायुरग्निश्व धर्मराट्।
>
> विप्रस्य दक्षिणे कर्णे नित्यं निष्ठन्ति देवताः॥
>
> Aditya, Vasu, Rudra, Vayu, Agni, Dharma gods reside in Brahmana's right ear.

Comment: Sloka 1 in the answer, "मुनिरब्रवीत"-the literary translation is "according to munis". You may review this part and if found proper by you, may change the   "according to Manu"  part in your answer, to- according to munis..Or else, it can also be changed to "Manurbraveet".Thank you.

Comment: @UdayKrishna thanks. I have fixed the shloka.

Comment: Thanks for the answer .My guess was the same,so i downloaded the PS and read it almost full today.But i cud find only the 2nd sloka u quoted.Even one of my other questions is been answered in the PS which i just saw that u have  answered as well.:)